# Regular expression for rest of line after first x characters

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of lines with IDs as the first six characters, and data I don't need after. Is there a way to identify everything after the ID section so Find and Replace can replace it with whitespace?

Comment: you literally just want to save the first six characters of every line? `^(.{6}).*$` replaced by `$1` (or `\1` or whatever your flavor uses)

Comment: If it's always 6 chars wouldn't cut work (slightly) more efficiently than regex ?  ie:  `cut -c1-6` ??

Comment: @Ditto unless he's on Windows. Or more specifically -- unless he doesn't have GNU tools :P

Comment: @Adam: Ah, true .. do we know what he's on though? O.o  lol

Answer (score 1):

```
 /.{6}\K.*//
```

If you want something more specific, please be more specific in your question.